# How to store the wordpress wp-content folder in local machine when running through docker compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have all set in my local machine for virtual machine shared folders. I have following code in my Docker compose file for Wordpress service. but not sure how the volumes work here. Can you please explain?

```
version: '2'

services:

  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    restart: unless-stopped

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:4.9.6
    ports:
      - 49160:80
    links:
      - database:mysql
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html/wp-content
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    restart: unless-stopped

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - database:db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Does the above volumes line of code mean, does it need to create a WordPress folder in my docker-compsose.yml file that I am currently running?

Or is it anyhow related to my shared folders in virtual machine?

Answer (score 5):

Basically volumes are instruments for Docker so it can retain data. Docker containers are generally designed to be stateless, but if you need to retain state/information between runs, that's where volumes come in.

You can create an unnamed volume in the following way:

```
volumes:
  - /var/www/html/wp-content
```

This will retain your wp-content folder in the internal volumes storage without a particular name.

A second way would be to give it a name, making it a named volume:

```
volumes:
  - mywp:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

And the final type, which is also what you are doing, is called a Volume Bind. This basically binds/mounts the content of a folder on your host machine in the container. So if you change a file in either place, it will be saved on the other.

```
volumes:
  - ./wordpress:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

In order to use your Volume Bind, you will need to create the folder "wordpress" in the folder where you're running the docker-compose.yaml (usually your root folder). Afterwards, when your installation changes within the container, it will also change on the bind and vice-versa.

EDIT: In your particular case the following should work:

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    restart: unless-stopped

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:4.9.6
    ports:
      - 49160:80
    links:
      - database:mysql
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./wordpress
        target: /var/www/html/wp-content
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    restart: unless-stopped

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - database:db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

Comment: Okay, I have manually created WordPress folder in the folder where docker-compose.yml is present. But even after I am running the container, the folder is not filling up with the wp-content folder contents. I am editing my question and adding entire dockercompose file of mine. Can you please check? BTW, when I run the application in browser it is giving me notification "The theme directory "twentyseventeen" does not exist.
ERROR: The themes directory is either empty or doesn’t exist. Please check your installation."

Comment: When I exec into Wordpress docker container, I cannot even see empty wp-content folder.

Comment: @m9m9m I edited my answer with how I would do the binding in your case. Note that I've bumped up the Version from 2 to 3.2, so it can use this syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a volume to your `docker-compose.yml` file will enable you to 'mount' content from your local file system into the running container.

So, about the following line here:

```
volumes:
  - ./wordpress:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

This means that whatever's in your local `wordpress` directory will be placed in the `/var/www/html/wp-content` directory inside your container. This is useful because it allows you to develop themes and plugins locally and automatically inject them into the running container.

To avoid confusion, I'd recommend renaming `wordpress` to something else, so it's clear that you're mounting only your WordPress content, and not core files themselves.

I have a similar setup here, in case you need another reference:

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/wp-skateboard